# Join table with composite key twice

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, trac

Given the table `ticket` with the primary key `id` and the table `ticket_custom` with the composite key `ticket,name` how can I join for `id = ticket and name=X and id = ticket and name=Y`.

The table `ticket_custom` allows the ticket table to be *extended*, it has the fields `ticket,name,value`.

I can do a single join:

```
SELECT id, summary, owner, ticket_custom.value
FROM ticket
INNER JOIN ticket_custom
ON id=ticket_custom.ticket AND ticket_custom.name='X'
```

I need something like:

```
SELECT id, summary, owner, ticket_custom.value, ticket_custom.value
FROM ticket
INNER JOIN ticket_custom
ON id=ticket_custom.ticket AND ticket_custom.name='X' AND ticket_custom.name='Y'
```

Where the first `ticket_custom.value` is the value for `id,x` and the second is for `id,y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT id, summary, owner, c1.value, c2.value
FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN ticket_custom c1  ON t.id = c1.ticket AND c1.name = 'X'
INNER JOIN ticket_custom c2  ON t.id = c2.ticket AND c2.name = 'Y'
```

Comment: I believe that will always return an empty result set except in the case X = Y

Comment: Great this is what I meant!

Comment: Yes, this is the canonical pattern for querying multiple custom fields at once.

Answer (score 0):

I this this should do the trick:

```
SELECT id, summary, owner, ticket_custom.value, ticket_custom.value
FROM ticket
INNER JOIN ticket_custom
ON ticket.id=ticket_custom.ticket
WHERE (ticket_custom.name='X' OR ticket_custom.name='Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe**

```
SELECT id, summary, owner, ticket_custom.value, ticket_custom.value
FROM ticket
INNER JOIN ticket_custom
ON id=ticket_custom.ticket AND ticket_custom.name='X' 
    OR id=ticket_custom.ticket AND ticket_custom.name='Y'
```

Comment: This would display `ticket_custom.value` for `id=$id,name='X'` twice not once for `id=$id,name='X'` and once for `id=$id,name='Y'`